# ARC Semantic Issue (Xcode): No known class method for selector 'mapIDWithIdentifier:' - XCode 15 & Flutter

Tags: flutter, xcode15

After upgrading to the new Xcode 15, I'm trying to run or build the app in iOS on the iPhone 15 pro max simulator but I face this error:

```
ARC Semantic Issue (Xcode): No known class method for selector 'mapIDWithIdentifier:'
/Users/.../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_maps_flutter_ios-2.3.1/ios/Classes/GoogleMapController.m:87:26

ARC Semantic Issue (Xcode): No known class method for selector 'mapWithFrame:mapID:camera:'
/Users/.../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_maps_flutter_ios-2.3.1/ios/Classes/GoogleMapController.m:92:26
```

The version of google_maps_flutter is 2.5.0, I tried to downgrade and upgrade it but nothing happened.

I cleared the cache many times, upgraded the pods, and did many things like flutter clean, cache clean, cache repair and so on.

I upgraded the flutter version of the app to 3.13.6 because I thought it's the problem but nothing new happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by going inside the .pub_cache files and removed the google_maps_flutter_ios-2.3.1, I think It's not the right solution but it made it work right now and didn't find any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

pod update GoogleMaps

Please update the GoogleMaps and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Delete Podfile.lock file and run again, I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I downgrade the google_maps_flutter_ios to 2.2.3 and it worked.

Add below in pub spec.yml

```
dependency_overrides:
  google_maps_flutter_ios: 2.2.3
```

Delete `Pods` and `Podfile.lock` in ios and then run `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` and `pod install`